# Python praw not copying link to clipboard

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, reddit, praw

Im attempting to make a reddit third party browser with praw and tkinter. However,i have ran into an issue that i am unable to understand. The app is supposed to copy the link to the clipboard when a certain button is clicked. However, it gives me this error instead:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lazar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "R:\Caca.pyw", line 69, in copy_post_link
    window.clipboard_append(submission.url)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'
```

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import prawcore
import praw

subreddit = "all"
LoadedPosts = []
content = ""
submission = ""
seperate_for_processing = ''
link = ''

#login
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='id',
                     client_secret='secret',
                     password='password',
                     user_agent='agent',
                     username='username')
#codes
window = Tk()

#script
window.title("OpenSnoo v1.0 Pre-Alpha release")

lbl = Label(window, text='No subreddit selected', font=("Arial Bold", 50))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

postname = Label(window, text='', font=("Arial Bold", 12))
postname.grid(column=0, row=2)

SubredditInput = Entry(window,width=20)
SubredditInput.grid(column=1, row=1)

def clicked():

    #change subreddits and load post ids into list
    subreddit = SubredditInput.get()
    poop = 'r/' + subreddit
    lbl.configure(text=poop)
    subreddit_true = reddit.subreddit(subreddit)
    LoadedPosts.clear()
    for submission in subreddit_true.new(limit=65):
        LoadedPosts.append(submission.id)
    
    #load newest submission instantly:
    seperate_for_processing = reddit.submission(id=LoadedPosts.pop(0))
    submission = seperate_for_processing
    postname.configure(text=submission.title)
    post_text.configure(text=submission.selftext)
    link = seperate_for_processing.url
    

finished = seperate_for_processing
btn = Button(window, text="Select subreddit", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=2, row=1)

post_text=Message(window,text = "")
post_text.grid(row=4,column=0)

def next_post():
    #load newest submission instantly:
    seperate_for_processing = reddit.submission(id=LoadedPosts.pop(0))
    submission = seperate_for_processing
    postname.configure(text=submission.title)
    post_text.configure(text=submission.selftext)
    link = seperate_for_processing.url
    window.clipboard_append(link)

def copy_post_link():
    window.clipboard_append(submission.url)
    window.update() # now it stays on the clipboard after the window is closed

btn_next = Button(window, text="Next", command=next_post)
btn_next.grid(column=3, row=1)

copy = Button(window, text="Copy link to clipboard", command=copy_post_link)
copy.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Anyways,this doesn't put anything in my clipboard when a press the button (function call is copy_post_link) and other parts of the program also cannot access the submission id and use it the way that is required for anything more than printing names to a terminal. I believe that this is because the submission is somehow attached to that loop that pop()'s the first id and therefore doesn't allow me to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any of `prawcore` or `praw`, so I can not run your code.

However, it seems to me that the name `submission` is only assigned to a **str**, and the **str** datatype does not have an attribute `.url`

Check what data type `reddit.submission(id=LoadedPosts.pop(0))` returns. From the error message I'd guess it's a **str**.

Answer (score 1):

After running your code, there are a few things I noticed.

Instead of appending the ID to the list, as `LoadedPosts.append(submission.id)` does, you should append the full praw Submission object so that you can access properties like url (which is a string). Frankly though a lot of this is somewhat confusing the way it's structured (mainly, having two variables `seperate_for_processing` and `submission` be equal to each other in most cases without a clear reason why you need two, that I can see).

I suggest: first consider refactoring this into a MVC framework: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm because right now it's very unclear what is being updated, when, and why. Secondly, simplify unnecessary variables, and finally — importantly — the functionality DOES copy the link to the keyboard when you hit 'next.' So that's a place to start, suggesting that the way the `next_post()` function operates ought to be used in considering a particular 'copy to keyboard' button.